# Detecting CBPeripheral object state change from "Connected" to "Disconnected" in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

Is there any why to detect CBPeripheral object state change from "Connected" to "Disconnected" in iOS.

Comment: Yes, through the `didDisconnect` `CBCentralManagerDelegate` function

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, Thank you for your response. Yes, this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detecting whether a `Core Bluetooth Peripheral` object is disconnected use a `centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)` instance method which tells the delegate that the central manager disconnected from a peripheral:

```
     func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, 
didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
                             error: Error?) {

         print(peripheral.state)    // CBPeripheralState
     }
```

Do not forget to set a `delegate` instance property that is the delegate object specified to receive peripheral events from a `CBPeripheralDelegate` protocol that provides updates on the use of a peripheral’s services:

```
weak var delegate: CBPeripheralDelegate? { get set }
```

The `CBPeripheralState` has three cases:

```
enum CBPeripheralState : Int {

    case disconnected = 0
    case connecting = 1
    case connected = 2
}
```

Comment: Hi @Andy. I have already used the proposed solution to fix my issue. However, thank you for your response.